# How do we explain the fact that x can be an element of Z (shared with X) as well in X U (Y − Z)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

When I draw the Venn diagram, it is pretty obvious that the portion of Z that was not shared by Y but shared by X also becomes a part of the Union of X with Y. This is not the same as (or equal to) the relative complement of Z with respect to union of X and Y. In that case C is totally excluded. Yet when it comes to displaying this inequality I keep having problems in ascertaining the fact that the relative complement of Z with respect to Y does not hinder a possible intersection of X and Z (sharing an element that was not included in Y) and I end up seeing the inequality as an equality. I hope I explained it clearly.

Comment: I think you are asking: how can it be true that both: $x \in X \cap Z$ and also $x \in X \cup (Y-Z)$. Right?

Comment: If I had cheddar cheese in my fridge, and I went to buy food and I put all of it in the fridge, except any of the cheese I bought. Do I have cheese in my fridge?